# TLS-Structure of certificate message

Tags: ssl, handshake

I'm implementing RFC 5246(TLS 1.2), and I'm stuck at the certificate message.I'm debugging the server with a combination of Openssl s_client and Browsers.The server hello message is received and interpreted fine, and with -msg option in openssl I can see the message has been interpreted properly as Client_hello, without any errors.
When the certificate message is sent, the browser doesn't respond, and openssl s_client with -msg doesn't respond either. Openssl s_client with -debug reads the message but doesn't respond after the server_hello_done message. No errors are logged.
I suspect the problem is with the structure of my certificate message, because anything I send after the Record layer length gets received without any errors, even if it's just random text or binary data.
Modifying the structure of the record layer to incorrect/inappropriate values throws an error with the appropriate error message, for example setting the version to 9.3 throws the error
 `5256:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number`
as expected.
This is the structure I am currently using:

/*Record layer*/

- One byte for the message type, two bytes for the protocol version(major and minor), and two bytes for the message length.

/*Handshake message data*/

- Two bytes for the length, two bytes for the certificate(s) length.Finally the certificate(s).

I'm currently working with a self-signed certificate, and neither the browser nor openssl s_client include a signature_algorithms extension in the Client_hello, so I send the certificate as it is, in .PEM format, and in plain text.Below is openssl's hex dump of the handshake thus far:

```
CONNECTED(00000164)
write to 0x14ad698 [0x13f1ffb] (210 bytes => 210 (0xD2))
0000 - 16 03 01 00 cd 01 00 00-c9 03 01 53 5e 5c d6 a0   ...........S^\..
0010 - 34 27 ea 22 ed 01 dc 36-bb 0b 84 1e 5a 58 3e d5   4'."...6....ZX>.
0020 - 95 4d 5f 81 9f 2a f0 27-75 fb 1f 00 00 5c c0 14   .M_..*.'u....\..
0030 - c0 0a 00 39 00 38 00 88-00 87 c0 0f c0 05 00 35   ...9.8.........5
0040 - 00 84 c0 12 c0 08 00 16-00 13 c0 0d c0 03 00 0a   ................
0050 - c0 13 c0 09 00 33 00 32-00 9a 00 99 00 45 00 44   .....3.2.....E.D
0060 - c0 0e c0 04 00 2f 00 96-00 41 00 07 c0 11 c0 07   ...../...A......
0070 - c0 0c c0 02 00 05 00 04-00 15 00 12 00 09 00 14   ................
0080 - 00 11 00 08 00 06 00 03-00 ff 01 00 00 44 00 0b   .............D..
0090 - 00 04 03 00 01 02 00 0a-00 34 00 32 00 01 00 02   .........4.2....
00a0 - 00 03 00 04 00 05 00 06-00 07 00 08 00 09 00 0a   ................
00b0 - 00 0b 00 0c 00 0d 00 0e-00 0f 00 10 00 11 00 12   ................
00c0 - 00 13 00 14 00 15 00 16-00 17 00 18 00 19 00 23   ...............#
00d2 - <SPACES/NULS>
read from 0x14ad698 [0x13edaab] (5 bytes => 5 (0x5))
0000 - 16 03 01 00 2c                                    ....,
read from 0x14ad698 [0x13edab0] (44 bytes => 44 (0x2C))
0000 - 02 00 00 26 03 01 53 5e-5c d6 4a 5a 5b 4d 63 38   ...&..S^\.JZ[Mc8
0010 - 57 47 53 45 4d 5b 3f 3c-5f 38 23 67 26 32 38 4c   WGSEM[?<_8#g&28L
0020 - 2e 67 47 67 28 56 00 00-2f                        .gGg(V../
002c - <SPACES/NULS>
read from 0x14ad698 [0x13edaab] (5 bytes => 5 (0x5))
0000 - 16 03 01 02 99                                    .....
read from 0x14ad698 [0x13edab0] (665 bytes => 665 (0x299))
0000 - 0b 02 96 02 94 2d 2d 2d-2d 2d 42 45 47 49 4e 20   .....-----BEGIN 
0010 - 43 45 52 54 49 46 49 43-41 54 45 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d   CERTIFICATE-----
0020 - 0a 4d 49 49 42 75 54 43-43 41 53 49 43 43 51 43   .MIIBuTCCASICCQC
0030 - 43 65 67 31 46 6f 4f 76-43 4b 6a 41 4e 42 67 6b   Ceg1FoOvCKjANBgk
0040 - 71 68 6b 69 47 39 77 30-42 41 51 55 46 41 44 41   qhkiG9w0BAQUFADA
0050 - 68 4d 51 73 77 43 51 59-44 56 51 51 47 45 77 4a   hMQswCQYDVQQGEwJ
0060 - 4c 0a 52 54 45 53 4d 42-41 47 41 31 55 45 41 78   L.RTESMBAGA1UEAx
0070 - 4d 4a 62 47 39 6a 59 57-78 6f 62 33 4e 30 4d 42   MJbG9jYWxob3N0MB
0080 - 34 58 44 54 45 30 4d 44-51 79 4d 54 45 32 4e 44   4XDTE0MDQyMTE2ND
0090 - 4d 30 4e 56 6f 58 44 54-45 31 4d 44 51 79 4d 54   M0NVoXDTE1MDQyMT
00a0 - 45 32 0a 4e 44 4d 30 4e-56 6f 77 49 54 45 4c 4d   E2.NDM0NVowITELM
00b0 - 41 6b 47 41 31 55 45 42-68 4d 43 53 30 55 78 45   AkGA1UEBhMCS0UxE
00c0 - 6a 41 51 42 67 4e 56 42-41 4d 54 43 57 78 76 59   jAQBgNVBAMTCWxvY
00d0 - 32 46 73 61 47 39 7a 64-44 43 42 6e 7a 41 4e 42   2FsaG9zdDCBnzANB
00e0 - 67 6b 71 0a 68 6b 69 47-39 77 30 42 41 51 45 46   gkq.hkiG9w0BAQEF
00f0 - 41 41 4f 42 6a 51 41 77-67 59 6b 43 67 59 45 41   AAOBjQAwgYkCgYEA
0100 - 72 51 71 76 50 36 4c 35-41 71 31 31 67 76 38 2b   rQqvP6L5Aq11gv8+
0110 - 2f 59 55 53 62 50 46 4b-34 66 51 71 30 74 42 79   /YUSbPFK4fQq0tBy
0120 - 36 53 39 6c 0a 78 6f 45-6d 50 47 79 52 49 7a 44   6S9l.xoEmPGyRIzD
0130 - 31 46 78 78 52 65 50 79-55 6a 69 78 63 39 66 41   1FxxRePyUjixc9fA
0140 - 59 6f 74 5a 31 53 71 71-2f 2b 37 77 69 52 2b 7a   YotZ1Sqq/+7wiR+z
0150 - 33 46 6f 65 51 58 73 53-64 32 78 32 44 4b 63 62   3FoeQXsSd2x2DKcb
0160 - 73 62 64 62 76 0a 2f 73-49 2b 68 63 57 39 4c 5a   sbdbv./sI+hcW9LZ
0170 - 48 4d 45 75 49 6a 4d 42-73 6f 6f 4d 52 6a 76 35   HMEuIjMBsooMRjv5
0180 - 79 78 79 50 67 38 33 35-34 66 46 6d 51 50 38 4a   yxyPg8354fFmQP8J
0190 - 49 73 54 54 48 31 54 56-5a 4f 47 48 79 49 62 76   IsTTH1TVZOGHyIbv
01a0 - 6e 34 7a 36 35 6b 0a 48-63 62 75 4f 52 38 43 41   n4z65k.HcbuOR8CA
01b0 - 77 45 41 41 54 41 4e 42-67 6b 71 68 6b 69 47 39   wEAATANBgkqhkiG9
01c0 - 77 30 42 41 51 55 46 41-41 4f 42 67 51 41 72 73   w0BAQUFAAOBgQArs
01d0 - 36 62 74 6f 38 6b 76 67-6b 48 70 4d 56 50 42 42   6bto8kvgkHpMVPBB
01e0 - 50 62 4e 71 6d 2f 62 0a-4a 78 4a 34 4a 78 5a 72   PbNqm/b.JxJ4JxZr
01f0 - 51 4c 6b 6a 48 7a 39 34-44 75 57 7a 64 67 41 6a   QLkjHz94DuWzdgAj
0200 - 56 2b 70 39 72 7a 65 76-37 56 65 57 44 49 5a 41   V+p9rzev7VeWDIZA
0210 - 78 39 6a 43 6b 65 39 59-51 4c 68 42 67 62 2b 7a   x9jCke9YQLhBgb+z
0220 - 48 73 6d 30 39 70 50 43-0a 4c 4f 50 37 4b 67 4b   Hsm09pPC.LOP7KgK
0230 - 42 78 6e 68 52 49 33 4f-43 48 41 39 6f 43 78 30   BxnhRI3OCHA9oCx0
0240 - 78 46 35 46 65 34 53 38-34 65 6b 30 5a 37 65 5a   xF5Fe4S84ek0Z7eZ
0250 - 4c 55 63 7a 52 41 6f 55-57 50 42 65 70 32 6e 62   LUczRAoUWPBep2nb
0260 - 44 77 39 78 6c 6e 30 57-49 0a 53 33 72 6d 2f 47   Dw9xln0WI.S3rm/G
0270 - 4d 6d 6e 4e 73 78 75 74-68 69 63 41 3d 3d 0a 2d   MmnNsxuthicA==.-
0280 - 2d 2d 2d 2d 45 4e 44 20-43 45 52 54 49 46 49 43   ----END CERTIFIC
0290 - 41 54 45 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d-0a                        ATE-----.
read from 0x14ad698 [0x13edaab] (5 bytes => 5 (0x5))
0000 - 0e 03 01                                          ...
0005 - <SPACES/NULS>
read from 0x14ad698 [0x13edaab] (5 bytes => -1 (0xFFFFFFFF))
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 724 bytes and written 0 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    Start Time: 1398693078
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PEM is certainly not the right format to send on the wire. You should send it in binary form (use a base-64 decoded version of this PEM content).

You'll also need to wrap this in other layers, since a `certificate_list` in the `Certificate` `struct` is expected.

If you want to learn a bit more about all this, it's probably worth looking at existing traffic produced by working implementations using Wireshark. Its [SSL wiki page](http://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL) even has an existing capture file that you can use.

(You're also mentioning you want to implement TLS 1.2, but you're sending `03 01`, which is for TLS 1.0, although this shouldn't matter very much at this stage of your implementation.)

Comment: I'm using version 3.1 because it's the highest Openssl supports for s_client.I've used the Wireshark page you mentioned, in combination with other resources,but none really shows the structure of the certificate message.They all delete the contents.But I should be able to capture the traffic myself for analysis.Thank you.

Comment: Some versions of OpenSSL that are not even too recent (a couple of years old at least) support TLS 1.2. Not sure what you mean by Wireshark and other tools "deleting" all the content. If you open the "snakeoil" example from their Wiki (even without setting up the private key), there's a row that says "Server Hello, Certificate, Server Hello Done". In the middle panel below, you can expand "Secure Socket Layer" -> "Certificate" and so on. Whenever you click on an entry, it will highlight the matching section in the hex dump in the bottom panel, including the certificates themselves.

Comment: This is what I mean `openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -debug -tls1`.If instead you provide `-tls2` or `-tls3`as an argument, Openssl doesn't recognize that as a valid argument.Of course Openssl has had support for TLS 1.2 for a while now.Perhaps I wasn't clear,but I meant most online tutotials on TLS omit the specifics of the structure of the certificate message.I have captured my own TLS traffic using wireshark and the tool works perfectly. All length fields except for that in the record layer are 3 bytes.That cleared up everything for me.

Comment: Try `openssl s_client help`, you'll notice `-tls1_1` and `-tls1_2` (not sure why you'd try `-tls2` or `-tls3` since there are no version 2 or 3 of TLS). In general, what you're trying to do is a very ambitious project. You'll certainly need to read the RFC a number of times (including the "Presentation Language" section at first).

Comment: Tried it. `-tls1_1` and `-tls1_2` are not listed.Raised an "unknown option" error when I tried them anyway. There have been three versions of TLS: 1.0(RFC 2246), 1.1(RFC 4346), and 1.2(RFC 5246). I count 3. My usage of "2" and "3" was not intended in this way however, I assumed that since Openssl identified v1.0 as -tls1, then v1.2 would be -tls2, and so forth.

Comment: Which version of OpenSSL are you using? (`openssl version`). Sure, there are 3 versions of TLS, but they're not called 1, 2 and 3 (they also match the SSL naming on the wire: 3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3). By the way, you'll generally not find the information you're after on "tutorial" meant to explain things nicely. It's far too specialised, and there are too few incentives for anyone to explain how to do it (since to do it properly, you'll have to read the RFC and its dependencies many many times unfortunately).

Comment: Version 1.0.01. I know they're not called that. I tried to explain why I used 1 and 2 in my prevoius comment. I also know they match the SSL naming convention-as you can see, it is implemented in the server.

Comment: Do you mean 1.0.0i? It might be worth getting a newer version anyway.